Dead Mac Pro 1.1 logic board after installing a PCI express video card
Two months ago I was given away a Mac Pro 1,1 (A1186), in perfect working condition. Some days later, I had the bright idea of testing a working PCI express video card I removed from a PC  on my Mac, but it didn’t turn on.
So I removed the video card, reinstalled the old one, and again, it didn’t turn on. I removed the 3V battery to reset the PRAM, replaced it with a new one, performed a SMC reset, and tried everything I read on the forums, with no luck. I checked the logic board status LED’s and I noticed they all remained off.
Suspecting the culprit was the PSU, I ordered a second-hand PSU on eBay (Delta DPS-980AB A), I installed it yesterday but my Mac still doesn’t turn on. No status lights, no clicking sound, no spinning fans. I checked all the connectors again. I tested it by unplugging  connector # 4 and shorting ‘PS_ON’ plug and ground together with a paper clip. The PSU switches on, all the fans start spinning, all the led’s on the RAM raiser light up, but the logic board LED’s don’t light up, the switch-on button doesn’t respond and as soon as I remove the paper clip, the PSU switches off.
Conclusion: the “new” PSU works fine, so does the old PSU (I tested the voltages on both of them), and my logic board is toasted, I’m afraid.
Is there any “miraculous” procedure to revive my Mac, or do I have to buy a second-hand logic board?

I doubt there's anything to be done; but frankly I wouldn't spend any money on an 18-year-old computer. Its functional use, outside of retro thrills, is pretty minimal, and not very energy efficient either.

You may have fried the logic board, but it's hard to diagnose from my location on the planet. Having worked on several of these behemoths (they weigh over 40lbs/18Kg) years ago, following static electricity discharge protocol was important. At the very least, you should reseat all boards, RAM, and ribbon cables, check to make sure you didn't put the battery in backwards, blow out dust, etc. I'd hazard a guess it might have a faulty power supply, too.
This box is so old, but it may be a worthy project to try revive it, if you have the time, expertise, funds and access to parts / test equipment.
Here's some information about working on MacPros I lifted from this document at Apple.com:
Work Inside Mac Pro

Before you open your Mac Pro, shut it down by choosing Apple  > Shut Down.
Important: Always shut down your Mac Pro before opening it to avoid damaging its internal components or the components you want to install. Do not open the computer or attempt to install items inside it while it is on.
Wait 10 minutes to allow the computer’s internal components to cool.
WARNING: Let your computer cool down before you touch the internal components, which may be very hot.
Touch the metal on the outside of your Mac Pro to discharge any static electricity from your body.
Important: Always discharge static electricity before you touch
any parts or install any components inside the computer. To avoid generating static, do not walk around the room until you finish installing the cards, memory, or internal storage device and close the computer.
Unplug all the cables and the power cord from the computer.
To avoid damaging internal components or the components you want to install, always unplug your Mac Pro. Don’t attempt to install items while it’s plugged in.
Your computer incorporates an interlock circuit that’s intended to protect you from hazardous energy and injury from moving fan blades when the fan is operating at high speed. Do not attempt to defeat the interlock circuitry.


Great points. I can’t even recall if this board will “boot” without a GPU…. So long ago since I worked on these…
